# How do I get more characters in the Museum?

Tags: kirbys-adventure

I unlocked a room on the level select screen that is apparently a Museum of various Kirby abilities.

When I went in, I picked the Sword ability (by accident, it was closest to the door) and then I found I couldn't move past the area where the Sword ability was.

I don't know if there were other abilities available to me, but it got me wondering.

Do I have to do anything special to unlock other abilities in the museum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one room in the museum. However, each different level will have its own museum. So, the museum is not one large building that houses abilities, but simply a one-stop-shop for a specific ability. Vegetable Valley's museum only has the Sword Ability, other ones will have different abilities. They're unlocked all in the same fashion, finding the right switch in the right stage. It won't give you every ability in the game, unfortunately - some you'll just have to find the right stage for quick access.

The list of abilities in museums is as follows:

- Vegetable Valley: Sword
- Ice Cream Island: Laser, Fire
- Butter Building: Hi Jump
- Grape Garden: Sleep (...), Ball
- Yogurt Yard: Stone, Tornado
- Orange Ocean: Wheel

Comment: Ah. That makes sense, I was just confused by the whole "pick the one you like" text you get when you first enter. :)

Comment: That's mostly because some of the later museums have more than one ability - I've updated my answer to include the list of abilities.

Comment: Sleep has to be one of the most useless abilities. :P